# How-to counting the total number of acronyms (\usepackage{acro} & \usepackage{xassoccnt})?

Tags: acro, xassoccnt

How-to counting the total number of acronyms (\usepackage{acro} & \usepackage{xassoccnt})?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    %   first-style=long-short,
    first-style=footnote,
    list/display=used,
    format/short=\bf
}
%
\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
    short=USA,
    long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
    short=EU,
    long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
    short=USSR,
    long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}
%
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totacro}
\preto\ac{%
    \stepcounter{totacro}
}
% 
\begin{document}

There are \TotalValue{totacro} acronyms in this document

\hrulefill

\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}

\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}

\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}

\hrulefill

\printacronyms[heading=none, sort]
\end{document}
```

The result I get:

[image]

Correct result:

There are **3** acronyms in this document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patching `\DeclareAcronym` will have the desired effect in your example, but I assume the aim is to track used acronyms.

You can iterate over all acronyms with `\AcroAcronymsMap` and use the `\acroifused<TF>`/`\acroifsingle<TF>` commands to filter as appropriate e.g.

```
\AcroAcronymsMap{
  \acroifusedT{#1}{
    \stepcounter{totacro}
  }
}
```

which will operate on the used state at that point in the document.
If you are using the `single` option you probably want to gate this with `\acroifsingleF` as well.

You can further refine this to filter or otherwise use other acronym properties through the macros documented in "25.3. Commands to be used in template definitions" in the package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totacro}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    first-style=footnote,
    list/display=used,
    format/short=\bfseries,
}

\DeclareAcronym{usa}{
    short=USA,
    long=United States of America,
}
\DeclareAcronym{eu}{
    short=EU,
    long=European Union,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ussr}{
    short=USSR,
    long=Union of Soviet Socialist Republics,
}

\begin{document}
There are \TotalValue{totacro} acronyms in this document

\hrulefill

\ac{usa}, \ac{usa}

\ac{eu}, \ac{eu}

\ac{ussr}, \ac{ussr}

\hrulefill

\printacronyms[heading=none, sort]

\AcroAcronymsMap{
  \acroifusedT{#1}{
    \stepcounter{totacro}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Dai Bowen. How to hide the \AcroAcronymsMap command? Maybe it can be added to \printacronyms or moved to the preamble of the document?

Comment: @Youra_P You can do something like `\newcommand\countacronyms{\AcroAcronymsMap{\acroifusedT{#1}{\stepcounter{totacro}}}}`, and you could patch that into `\printacronyms` however you like.

Comment: Thank you, @Dai Bowen.